# Round variable to 1 decimal javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding

I have a litte script that adds 0.2 every second. It shows 15 decimals but I only want 1. How do I do this in JavaScript? I tried it by myself but I couldn't do it.

This is what I got so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/0qhx7s4t/

```js
var doughnut = 0;
show_value();
setInterval(function(){
    doughnut += 0.2;
    show_value();
}, 1000);

function show_value(){
    document.getElementById("co").innerHTML = doughnut;
}
```

```html
<li><label id="co"></label> CO&#178;</li>
```

Comment: See [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method:

```js
var doughnut = 0;
show_value();
setInterval(function(){
    doughnut += 0.2;
    show_value();
}, 1000);

function show_value(){
    document.getElementById("co").innerHTML = doughnut.toFixed(1);
}
```

```html
<li><label id="co"></label> CO&#178;</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toFixed(1)`

```js
var doughnut = 0;
show_value();
setInterval(function(){
    doughnut += 0.2;
    show_value();
}, 1000);

function show_value(){
    document.getElementById("co").innerHTML = doughnut.toFixed(1);
}
```

```html
<li><label id="co"></label> CO&#178;</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.round(num * 10) / 10` : https://jsfiddle.net/0qhx7s4t/1/